# Handling 'none' when trying to find the index? of a value that doesn't exist in Rebol?

Tags: indexing, rebol, rebol2

I have a `block!` `x: ["one" "two" "three"]`

`index? find x "two"` returns... 2

`index? find x "four"` returns...

`** Script Error: index? expected series argument of type: series port
** Near: index? find x "twos"`

What's the best way to have index? return `none` rather than the error?

Comment: I corrected your commands probably as they were meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>> help index?
USAGE:
    INDEX? series /xy

DESCRIPTION:
     Returns the index number of the current position in the series.
     INDEX? is an action value.

ARGUMENTS:
     series -- (Type: series port)

REFINEMENTS:
     /xy -- Returns index as an XY pair offset.
```

index? expects a series. If the argument is none, it will raise an error.

```
>>  find x "four"
== none
```

You can either check if the argument exists or is a series or guard against the error e.g.

```
>> if  series? i: find x "four" [index? i]
== none
```

or

```
>> attempt [index? find x "four" none]
== none
```